# Can i plot different parameter differential equation phase plane in a line?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, list-manipulation

In order to compare with different parameter,can i use `StreamPlot` plot them in a line, for example:

$$\dot{x} = Ax$$

When $A = [-1,0;0,-2]$, i can use code as follows,

```
linearsys = 
  StreamPlot[{-x, -2 y}, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
   StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", StreamPoints -> 24, 
   StreamScale -> 0.15, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
Manipulate[
 Show[linearsys, 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
      NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t], y'[t] == -2 y[t], 
        Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, 
    T}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {{T, 0.1}, 0.1, 10}, {{point, {4, 4}}, 
  Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

If $A = [\lambda_1,0;0,\lambda_2],~(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=(1,2), ~(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=(1,1),)$, how can i use `Table` to plot `StreamPlot` and `Manipulate` respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite your code to directly incorporate the matrix $a$:

```
a = {{-1, 0}, {0, -2}};
linearsys = 
  StreamPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
   StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", StreamPoints -> 24, 
   StreamScale -> 0.15, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
Manipulate[
 Show[linearsys, ParametricPlot[Evaluate[First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
      NDSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == a.{x[t], y[t]}, 
        Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, T}, 
        PlotStyle -> Red]], {{T, 0.1}, 0.1, 10}, {{point, {4, 4}}, Locator}]
```

Now you can change the $a$ matrix at the top and it will plot the flow lines for that $a$ matrix.

BTW -- Ben, where did you get that code from? It is always good form to reference the source of code when it is not original.

Comment: yeah,i forget the original,because i have make some change according mma official document.Thank you, i will try to find it.